# Error while initializing node sdk in hyperledger fabric

Tags: sdk, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I'm trying to connect to the node SDK in hyperledger Fabric using my networkConnection.yaml for 3 organizations with 2 peers each and a kafka orderer but I get the following error:

```
2019-02-04T12:34:45.710Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 6 Peers. Last error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
Error processing transaction. Error: Unable to initialize channel. 
Attempted to contact 6 Peers. Last error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 6 Peers. Last error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
at Network._initializeInternalChannel (/home/alberto/ibotics-network-1/application/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:127:12)
Disconnect from Fabric gateway.
Issue program complete.
```

Thank you

My Fabric network is running on Gcloud in docker swarm in 3 instances (16.04 LTS).